# how to force the input() prompt to be printed before getting the user input (using idlex)

Tags: python, input

I would like to get user input using the `input()` function.
My problem is that the prompt text doesn't show up until *after* the user enters the answer to `input`.

Example instruction:

```
res  = input('Say something:')
```

How to make the 'Say something:' text show up before getting the user input instead of after?

Possibly relevant information:

- I am using IDLEX (https://github.com/serwy/idlex) as an IDE and start it using this instruction:
  `python -m idlexlib.launch` (as recommended by the instructions)
- The input code works as expected when run from IDLE or from the command line, so this seems specific to idlex or the way I call it.
- This is using python 3 on Windows 10.
- I've looked into questions like these
  [How can I flush the output of the print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function)
  and tried `import sys; sys.stdout.flush()` without success.

thanks for any help!

Comment: your code is correct. `input` statement never behave like this. this is definitely a problem with IDLEX. I suggest you use vscode or sublime text